# Let $f(x)=x^2-kx$ and $g(x)=x^3-kx$, such that for a rational number $\alpha$, $f(\alpha)$ and $g(\alpha)$ both are rational numbers. Find k

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

Let $f(x)=x^2-kx$ and $g(x)=x^3-kx$, $k\in\mathbb{R^+}$ be two real valued functions such that for a rational number $\alpha$, $f(\alpha)$ and $g(\alpha)$ both are rational numbers.

Find the range of values that $k$ can take.

**My Attempt**

If $k=1$ then given condition is trivially true. But can there be other values.

If $m$ and $n$ be rational numbers such that $\alpha^2-k\alpha=m$ and $\alpha^3-k\alpha=n$.

This would imply that $k$ is rational since $\alpha,m$ and $n$ are all rational

Also by eliminating $k$, we have $\alpha^2(\alpha-1)=n-m$.

But after this I reach some kind of dead end.

Comment: For any $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$ we have that $f(\alpha), g(\alpha) \in \mathbb Q$? Or are there some other restraints on $\alpha$ as well?

Comment: None given. But one thing comes to mind is tha $k^2+4m$ must be a perfect square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is a bit unclear. I think that you are saying that for a fixed rational $\alpha$, we have $f(\alpha)$ and $g(\alpha)$ are both rational. Then what possible values of $k$ are there (depending possibly on $\alpha$)?

That is, we know only that

\begin{align}
  \alpha^2 - k \alpha &= a \in \mathbb{Q} \\
  \alpha^3 - k \alpha &= b \in \mathbb{Q}.
\end{align}

If $\alpha = 0$, then $k$ can be anything and this is uninteresting. Suppose now that $\alpha \neq 0$. Then we can divide by $\alpha$ and find

\begin{align}
  \alpha - k &= a' \in \mathbb{Q} \\
  \alpha^2 - k &= b' \in \mathbb{Q}.
\end{align}

The first equation tells us that $k = \alpha - a' \in \mathbb{Q}$, and thus $k$ must be rational. Clearly any rational $k$ suffices.

We gain no new information from $g$, and we conclude that $k$ can be any rational when $\alpha \neq 0$, and otherwise $k$ has no restrictions.